# node/add url redirect

Tags: 7, navigation, redirection

I have two group content types (I use OG groups) which are still under development. I created dummy content types so that these links will appear in the group content creation links.

But they are not ready yet. Instead i would like to redirect the user when he clicks on the link to an article which basically describes what the functionality is and is under development.

I googled and searched drupal answers for this but could not find anything that fits my problem. Please let me know if someone knows how to redirect node creation links in a group context to a static article page. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `hook_menu_link_alter()` to hide those links. For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_link_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_link_alter(&$link) {
  if ($link['link_path'] == 'node/add/dummy-type')) {
    $link['hidden'] = 1;
  }
}
```

Or can use `hook_menu_alter()` to redirect to other URL. For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/add/dummy-type']['page callback'] = 'drupal_goto';
  $items['node/add/dummy-type']['page arguments'] = array('node/1');
}
```

You can also use `hook_menu_alter()` to hide the links:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/add/dummy-type']['access callback'] = FALSE;
}
```